# Activating Add-on, getting: ImportError: No module named 'bpy.utils.previews', 'bpy.utils' is not a package

Tags: add-on

Add-on  Pro Lighting Skies Demo

[image]

This message error pops up when I follow the steps on how to download.  Somebody please help me.  I followed Andrew Price's directions on his website, Blender Guru, but it will not work.

Comment: I've modified your question to be more useful to future users who search for the error or problems installing this add-on.

Answer (score 4):

You need to update to [Blender 2.75](http://www.blender.org/download/). Versions prior to this don't have `bpy.utils.previews` which is used for custom ui icons and preview images. You will also need to install the add-on again, probably.

Answer (score 1):

You're either having trouble importing the addon correctly, or there's a bug in the addon.

Best way to import the addon is to leave the addon package inside a ZIP file and then choose the install from file option.

If, after loading the addon this way, you still get this error, you need to report it back to Andrew.